# Why do “would” and “could” make questions polite?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

**An excerpt of the article from [thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/asking-polite-questions-1211095):**

> **Key Words That Make Direct Questions More Polite** 
> In informal situations, one could use the word “can” in a direct sentence. In the
> United States, “can” is considered to be incorrect for written English
> in particular because, in the past, it was not a word used when asking
> for something. Saying “May I have” instead of “Can I have” is
> preferred in the U.S. In the United Kingdom, the word is not frowned
> upon. Cambridge University publishes English teaching materials with
> the phrase “Can you lend me,” “Can I have,” etc.
>
> **In both countries, questions with “can” are made more polite by using
> “could:”**
>
> *Excuse me, could you help me pick this up? Pardon me, could you help
> me? Pardon me, could you give me a hand? Could you explain this to me?*
>
> **“Would” can also be used to make questions more polite:**
>
> *Would you lend me a hand with the wash? Would you mind if I sat here?
> Would you let me borrow your pencil? Would you like something to eat?*

**“Would” in [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/could):**

> **Expressing a polite request.**
>
> *‘would you pour the wine, please?’
> ‘Would you please turn around?’
> ‘Would you mind clarifying your comment, Alison?’
> ‘Ruth, would you go
> with me to London?’*

**“Could” in [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/could):**

> **Used in making** suggestions or **polite requests**.
> *‘you could always ring
> him up’ 
> ‘could I use the phone?’
> ‘We had a
> letter to say they had not received the form and could I make a
> request for a new one.’
> ‘Where did you find the information that you
> used to write it, and could you suggest a few books for me?’
> ‘I would
> be grateful if any readers could tell me more.’
> ‘Is there a small
> heater you could recommend for when the icy weather returns?’*

Why do “would” and “could” sound more polite than “will” and “can”?

*‘Ruth, would you go with me to London?’* Why not: *‘Ruth, will you go with me to London?’*

*‘Could I use the phone?* Why not: *‘Can I use the phone?*

What tense or mood do “would” and “could” belong to?

Is it the subjunctive mood or the past tense, or something else?

From [grammar-monster.com](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm):

> **The subjunctive mood is the verb form used to explore
> a hypothetical situation (e.g., *If I were you*) or to express a wish, a
> demand, or a suggestion (e.g., *I demand he be present*).**
> …
> *If it were me, I'd go.* (As this
> explores a hypothetical situation, was becomes were.)
> *I wish it were
> real.* (As this expresses a wish, was becomes were.)
> *It is imperative
> that the game begin at once.* (As this expresses a demand, begins
> becomes begin.)
> *I propose he work full time.* (As this expresses a
> suggestion, works becomes work.)

Do requests with “would” and “could” seem hypothetical and therefore more polite? And with “will” and “can” they look more affirmative and therefore more rude?

*‘Ruth, would you go with me to London?’* – seems hypothetical and therefore more polite.
*‘Ruth, will you go with me to London?’* – seems affirmative and therefore more rude.

*‘Could I use the phone?’* – seems hypothetical and therefore more polite.
*‘Can I use the phone?’* – seems affirmative and therefore more rude.

It was my guess.

What are the reasons for using “would” and “could” instead of “will” and “can” to impart politeness to requests? Perhaps there is some psychological explanation for this. Maybe some ways of people’s thinking  are reflected in it.

Comment: https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Usage/faq0002.html

Comment: Yes, _would_ and _could_ are more polite. The following text is from _Practical English Usage_, which is quoted more fully in an answer to a similar question elsewhere on this site. _"We can make requests (and also questions, suggestions and statements) less direct (and so more polite) by using verb forms that suggest 'distance' from the immediate present reality. Past tenses are often used to do this."_ https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245613/was-wondering-present-tense-tense-concordance

Comment: The concept of "distancing" in @Shoe's comment above is interesting. I've always assumed that politeness is culturally and historically determined, but "distancing" makes sense because it allows the petitioner to appear less demanding, leaving the decision open to the choice of the person being asked. With a more direct expression, the desired action seems less in the control of the person being asked.

Comment: Symbolic distancing is also involved in using plural for polite second person (_thou_ -> _you_, _tu_ -> _vous_), and also using third person for the same purpose (_Du/Ihr_ -> _Sie_). Don't forget that this notion of distance is not located on a plane. There's a slope involved, and the speaker has to decide whether they're addressing upslope or downslope, and how far away they are from the addressee or referent. You can see the limiting case in [Javanese kromo, madhya, and ngoko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_language#Registers), which are essentially three different languages.

Comment: @Stuart F Thanks for your comment. The article on your link is more about distinguishing between  “would” and “could”. However, there is the opinion on why “could” can be polite. I think “it expresses the idea of probability” and  “used to indicate tentativeness” may be true.

Comment: @Shoe Thank you. Interesting thought. But why is it exactly the past tense? It looks more like the subjunctive.

Comment: @Eagle. The subjunctive is seen in expressions such as "_If I __were__ you_ or _It is important that he __be__ here early_. _Would_ and _could_ are not subjunctive verb forms. They are however used in conditionals. E.g. _Would you help me if I paid you?_ or _I could help you if I weren't ill_. Neither of your _would/could_ sentences seem like conditionals (although an _if clause_ can more plausibly be added to the _would_ question than to the _could_ question).

Comment: @Shoe yet the conditional is used in other languages for the same purpose.  (Also, not only questions are affected; it's similarly more polite to say "I would like a glass of water" than "I want a glass of water.")

Comment: @phoog. I'm not sure that "_I would like a beer_" can be considered a conditional. I don't see a condition attached to the statement or (implied) request. But certainly, other languages use subjunctive forms in such utterances. E.g. German: "_Ich hätte gern ein Bier._"

Comment: @Shoe French: "je voudrais une bière."  Similarly, the English "I would like" is certainly conditional in form, if no longer in function.  I suppose it arose from a construction along the lines of "I would like a beer, if you would be so kind...."  Oh, and German doesn't have a conditional per se; it [uses its subjunctive for that purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#German), so the fact that _ich hätte_ is subjunctive does not establish that the expression isn't conditional.

Comment: @phoog. You are right to distinguish between form and function. You might want to ask a separate question to our resident expert linguists as to whether "_I would like a beer_" is rightly considered a conditional. German has the "would + lexical verb" equivalent: "_Ich würde gern ein Bier haben_"

Comment: @Shoe and English is moving in the opposite direction from German, since conditional form is increasingly being used for subjunctive function ("if he would have written it down, he wouldn't have forgotten it").

Comment: Note that not-quite-so-politely-hedged requests are also considered acceptable, and this has been covered elsewhere on ELU: "Would you shut the window, please, John?" [more solicitous] //  "Would you shut the window, please, John" [more brusque, businesslike].

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line here is that it is reducing a command to a request. "Pour me more wine" is a command, and "Would you pour me more wine?" is a request. Nobody likes to be ordered what to do, and so turning it into a request is considered more polite.

You might consider this. (Doesn't that sound nicer than me demanding that you: "Consider this.") I remember watching a TV show where a museum guard had to clear out a room of people. He approached someone and said "I'm going to have to ask you to leave." This is a curious phrase, don't you think? He didn't say "Get out." It is almost as if he was saying "In the near future I am going to have to tell you to leave, but if you do it now, of your own accord, then it'll be less awkward for us both, and less subservient for you."

So many of the niceties such as "could" or "would" are there to transform a demeaning demand into a more digestible request. Requesting is considerably more polite than ordering.

Comment: The question is about "would" vs. "will" and "could" vs. "can" in interrogatives. You are talking about imperative sentences.

Comment: I am grateful to you for your answer. It contains rational thoughts, but that’s not exactly what I asked. An order is: “Open the window”. A request is: “Can you open the window?” However, it is more polite to say: “Could you open the window?” I asked about the difference between the last two options. My question is: “Why do ‘would’ and ‘could’ make questions polite?”

Answer (score 0):

> Both ‘**can**’ and ‘ **could**’ are modal verbs that refer to ‘a possibility’, ‘ability’ or ‘capacity’.
>
> [Difference between Can and Could](https://byjus.com/english/difference-between-can-and-could/#:%7E:text=Both%20%27can%27%20and%20%27%20could,ability%27%20or%20%27capacity%27.&text=%27Can%27%20refers%20to%20a%20general,not%20necessarily%20a%20general%20truth.)

*So what is the primary difference between both?*

Well,

> ‘Can’ refers to a general truth or something that has a strong possibility.
>
> ‘Could’ refers to something that has a weak possibility, or something that might happen, but not necessarily a general truth.
>
> (ibid)

This means, even if 'can' and 'could' both refer to possibility of something, the latter one seems more polite as it does not necessarily imply that the person must be able to do the task but rather more of an assumption that it might just be [possible](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/could-can-and-would).

This holds true even for *'will'* and *'would'*, the latter one when used makes the listener feel the there is quite a possibility that he/she be able to do the said task but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

*Would* and *could* are used for imagined situations. Thus, when they are used  in place of *will* and *can*, which express "something that is to happen" or a wish and possibility, they sound more polite; *would* and *could* imply that that which is being asked may or may not happen, regardless of whether it be possible or not, or it be desirable or not.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will)

> History and Etymology for will
>
> Verb (1)
>
> Middle English (1st & 3rd singular present indicative), from Old English wille (infinitive wyllan); akin to Old High German wili (3rd singular present indicative) wills, Latin velle to wish, will

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can)

> History and Etymology for can
>
> Verb (1)
>
> Middle English (1st & 3rd singular present indicative), from Old English; akin to Old High German kan (1st & 3rd singular present indicative) know, am able, Old English cnāwan to know — more at KNOW

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by the references to etymology. However, I like your idea about imaginary situations. This is similar to the meaning of the subjunctive mood. Perhaps, indeed, such requests are subconsciously perceived by people as relating to an imaginary, unreal world, and therefore in no way encroaching on their will in the real world. And that's why they sound polite. I voted for your answer, but I'm not accepting it yet, because I want to study other answers.

Comment: I just wanted to substantiate the definitions I gave of will and can.